# How can we implement an "underlay" in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I see [cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/) has support for an [overlay](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/overlay), but could not find any way on how to draw a similar shape, but one which is behind the node body, instead of on top of it.

Overlay: [image: 3]]

My use case is basically to have something that does **not** darken the node body when the node is active. Can we somehow manipulate the z-index of the overlay, so that it is shown below the node?

Comment: You can use a compound node for this, just add a node to your elements and add the corresponding styles to that node.

Comment: @StephanT. Good suggestion. Thanks. I'll try it out.

Comment: See also https://github.com/classcraft/cytoscape.js-canvas

Comment: @maxkfranz  This will justify my use better as I would not have to deal with the added complexity of a compound node. Thanks.